# Asteroids clone in Monogame spawns the asteroids with the same position, rotation and direction

Tags: c#, monogame

EDIT: Fixed the problem. I created a new Random for every asteroid so there wasn't enough time between them. But when I stepped trough the code manually it was enough time to not create the same value.

Here's the code. Control with WASD, shoot with space and press "L" to spawn an asteroid.

https://github.com/Geblin/Monogame-Asteroids

The asteroids split into 2-3 smaller asteroids when shot at and it's those smaller ones that have the same values, even though I give them random ones. I've stepped trough the code and it seems like they get different values initially.

Here's the Asteroid class. So I input a scale and a position so I can spawn smaller asteroids on different positions. The angle and speed is randomly selected here.

```
public Asteroid(Texture2D texture, float scale, Vector2 pos)
{
    rand = new Random();
    this.texture = texture;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.pos = pos;
    angle = degreesToRadian(rand.Next(0,360));
    direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));
    origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);
    isVisible = true;
    sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture.Width, texture.Height);
    boundingCircle = new BoundingCircle(pos, texture, scale);
    speed = (float)rand.NextDouble() * (3 - 1) + 1;           

    setupRotation();
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{           
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, pos, sourceRectangle, Color.White, angle, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    boundingCircle.x = pos.X;
    boundingCircle.y = pos.Y;

    pos += direction * speed;

    //Sets the asteroids bounds
    if (pos.X > 2120)
        pos.X = -200;
    else if (pos.X < -200)
        pos.X = 2120;
    if (pos.Y > 1280)
        pos.Y = -200;
    else if (pos.Y < -200)
        pos.Y = 1280;

    angle += (float)rotationDirection;
}

public float degreesToRadian(int degrees)
{
    float radian = (float)(Math.PI / 180) * degrees;
    return radian;
}

//Sets a random rotation speed and rotation direction.
public void setupRotation()
{
    rotationDirection = rand.NextDouble() * (0.01f - 0.005f) + 0.005f;

    int x = rand.Next(2);
    if (x == 1)
        rotationDirection = -rotationDirection;
}
```

Here's the asteroid spawner class. The SetRandomSpawn method is for the first spawning asteroids. Those that spawn outside of the window and drifts in. In the main class I have the code that checks collisions between the lasers and asteroids and then spawns the smaller ones at the same position.

```
public AsteroidSpawner(List<Asteroid> asteroidList)
{
    rand = new Random();
    this.asteroidList = asteroidList;
}

public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
{
    texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Asteroid");
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroidList)
        asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    UpdateAsteroids(gameTime);

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.L))
        SpawnAsteroid(SetRandomSpawn(), 1f, 1);
}

public void SpawnAsteroid(Vector2 pos, float scale, int amount)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
    {
        Asteroid newAsteroid = new Asteroid(texture, scale, pos);
        asteroidList.Add(newAsteroid);
    }
}

public void UpdateAsteroids(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroidList)
    {
        asteroid.Update(gameTime);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < asteroidList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!asteroidList[i].isVisible)
        {
            asteroidList.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

//Sets a random spawn outside of screen bounds
public Vector2 SetRandomSpawn()
{
    int side = rand.Next(4);

    //Each number represents a side

    switch (side)
    {
        // Left
        case 0:
            return new Vector2(2120, rand.Next(0, 1080));

        // Top
        case 1:
            return new Vector2(rand.Next(0, 1920), 1280);

        // Right
        case 2:
            return new Vector2(-200, rand.Next(0, 1080));

        //Bottom
        case 3:
            return new Vector2(rand.Next(0, 1920), -200);

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect CrystalTypeEnum");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] not link to repo

Answer (score 1):

The seed of the `Random` object is time based, and because the spawner creates an `Asteroid`, and hence a `Random` in a loop, the random numbers generated are the same.

From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

You can see this effect with a wee test:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var rand = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
}
```

... which outputs:

```
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
1337050944
```

Fix this by re-using the same `Random` (suggest your spawner creates an `Asteroid` then sets its position).